# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch on a non-rooted Android 4.4 device somehow?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android, phone

I have an Android 4.4 ARM phone and it is not rooted.

I would like to try out Ubuntu Touch on it.

Is it possible to install it, dual boot it with Android or run it from a VM?

**UPDATE**

My device is not in the list of Supported devices.
Does it means that it is impossible to install it (without damaging the device)?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/952125/158442 and https://ubports.com/

Comment: If your device is not in the list of supported devices, don't risk it. You may raise a request with ubports.com people.