# Ubuntu for Samsung tablet

Tags: system-installation

I wish to convert my Samsung tablet to Ubuntu. Where can I find rooting and installation procedures?

Many thanks,

Martin

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  **:-)** Unfortunately, Samsung is in the "abandoned ports"  for [Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices), so unless you want to install an old version and be stuck with it, there is nothing we can do here as we don't support abandoned versions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)